# How do I make an animation start from the current location of the div?

Tags: html, css

Basically title. This is a small part of my code:

```css
.floor {
    position: absolute;
    top: 140px;
    height: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    animation: floorAnimation 2s infinite linear;
}

#floor1 {
    right: -200px;
    background-color: red;
}

#floor2 {
    right: 0px;
    background-color: green;
}

#floor3 {
    right: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
}

#floor4 {
    right: 400px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#floor5 {
    right: 600px;
    background-color: orange;
}

#floor6 {
    right: 800px;
    background-color: purple;
}

#floor7 {
    right: 1000px;
    background-color: brown;
}

@keyframes floorAnimation {
    from {
        right: -200px;
    }
    to {
        right: 1000px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id = "floor1" class = "floor"></div>
<div id = "floor2" class = "floor"></div>
<div id = "floor3" class = "floor"></div>
<div id = "floor4" class = "floor"></div>
<div id = "floor5" class = "floor"></div>
<div id = "floor6" class = "floor"></div>
<div id = "floor7" class = "floor"></div>
```

Notice how the `right`  of each div id is different, but on the animation itself, all of them start from `right: -200px;` -right now, they all teleport to -200px and overlap with themselves and do the animation at once.

How do I make it that for example, instead of all immediately starting on `right: -200px;`, each div would finish the first iteration from it's current `right`  and then on the second iteration it would teleport to `right: -200px;` and continue the animation as normal?

Comment: Do you have an existing animation in mind that we could see (from another website I mean) ?

Comment: Add expected result screenshot or something else

Comment: You can't give each div a different `right` position, as such, but you can give each one a different, negative `animation-delay`.